# How to call Loadig From $rootsscope

Tags: angularjs

Please Help me how can i call $scope.Loading from $rootscope

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Lodge="Hello Loading....."
    })
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {    
    })
```

**HtmlPage**

i Simply call as

```
{{Lodge}}
```

Comment: Use `$rootScope.Lodge = "..."` although I don't recommend using `$rootScope` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Nokolaj Dam  oo Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a way to do:

In HTML

```
<div ng-show="loading">Hello loading</div>
//you can add some CSS if you use like this maybe a transparent BG color etc.
```

In Controller

```
$scope.loading = true; //loader enabled
$scope.loading = false; //loader disabled
//You can use the same with $rootScope too. you can enable and disable wherever needed by just making it true or false;
```

Comment: @Ujjjwala Thank for ur feedback bt my requerement  is some different

Comment: You can't use $scope there in run!. Use $rootScope only